# Combine variables from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning, I have the following dataframe:

```
dft
```

```
Country Brazil  Brazil  Brazil  Brazil  Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Bolivia Chile   Chile   Chile   Chile   Chile   Chile   Chile   Chile
Order   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
Product TV  TV  Computer    TV  TV  Computer    Computer    Computer    TV  Radio   TV  Radio   Radio   Radio   Computer    Computer    TV  TV  Radio   TV
```

I want to group the dataframe into something like:

```
Country Brazil Brazil Brazil Bolívia Bolívia Bolívia Chile Chile Chile
Order 7 3 0 25 21 22 22 55 31 58
Product Tv Computer Radio Tv Computer Radio Tv Computer Radio
```

How can I make it?

Comment: what's the logic behind the combination? how you achieve the result? where does the `Order=7` for Brazil TV come from?

Comment: I actually want to group all the orders of each product for each of these countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the by `country` and `product` and sum by `order`:

df2 = df.groupby(['Country','Product'])['Order'].sum()